# tell mysql to store table in memory or on disk

Tags: mysql

I have a rather large (10M+) table with quite a lot data coming from IOT devices.
People only access the last 7 days of data but have access on demand to older data.
as this table is growing at a very fast pace (100k/day) I choose to split this table in 2 tables, one only holding the 7 last days of data, and another one with older data.
I have a cron running that basically takes the oldest data and moves it to the other table..

How could I tell Mysql to only keep the '7days' table loaded in memory to speed up read access and keep the 'archives' table on disk (ssd) for less frequent access ?

Is this something implemented in Mysql (Aurora) ?
I couldn't find anything in the docs besides in memory tables, but these are not what I'm after.

Comment: You can't tell it to keep specific table data in memory. Creating another table that holds 7 days' data is, sadly, not going to help optimize anything as MySQL doesn't operate the way you (intuitively) think it does. Depending on the engine (InnoDB), you can increase the amount of memory MySQL is allowed to allocate to keep indexes and table data within it. Now, it's unclear whether there's anything actually wrong - are write slow, are reads slow, are you experiencing any issue or are you simply prematurely optimizing?

Comment: Essentially prematurely optimizing, I see an increase in read speeds when table is less populated. Maybe I shoud split these 2 tables accross 2 different servers then ?

Comment: You can further optimize read using [table partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html). You can then distribute I/O across multiple files (and disks, if you have control over file placement) without any significant changes in your code. Partitioning by date (i.e. week of year) will limit your queries on a couple of files (current and past week).